# add photo, custom uitableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

How to design a tableview similar to contact application in iphone.........
and also how to implement add photo image from local photo library which is there in contact application....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Contact App uses an indexed tableView.

Images from the local photo library can be accessed by an UIImagePickerController (I present him in a modalViewController). The standard source property is your local Photo library UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary. So it's exactly what you need :-)